# IOResult methods deprecated

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am new to Scala and am using the method def process however getting build errors like "method wasSuccessful in class IOResult is deprecated (since 2.6.0): status is always set to Success(Done)
case Success((sftpResult, updateList)) if sftpResult.wasSuccessful =>". My question is how would I then implement this in my code? I apologise if the question seems stupid.

```
    override def process(changedAfter: Option[ZonedDateTime], changedBefore: Option[ZonedDateTime])
                        (implicit fc: FlowContext): Future[(IOResult, Seq[Operation.Value])] = {
      val now = nowUtc
      val accountUpdatesFromDeletions: Source[AccountUpdate, NotUsed] =
        dbService
          .getDeleteActions(before = now)
          .map(deletionEventToAccountUpdate)

      val result = getAccountUpdates(changedAfter, changedBefore)
        .merge(getErrorUpdates)
        .merge(accountUpdatesFromDeletions)
        .mapAsync(4)(writer.writePSVString)
        .viaMat(creditBureauService.sendUpdate)(Keep.right)
        .mapAsync(4)(au =>
          for {
            _ <- dbService.performUpdate(au)
            _ <- performActionsDelete(now, au)
          } yield au.operation
        )
        .toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.both)
        .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
        .run()

      tupleFutureToFutureTuple(result) andThen {
        case Success((sftpResult, updateList)) if sftpResult.wasSuccessful =>
          val total = updateList.size
          val deleted = updateList.count(_ == Operation.DELETED)
          val updated = updateList.count(_ == Operation.UPDATED)
          val inserted = updateList.count(_ == Operation.INSERTED)
          log.info(s"SUCCESS! Uploaded $total accounts to Equifax.")
          log.info(s"There were $deleted deletions, " +
            s"$updated updates and " +
            s"$inserted insertions to the database")
          monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.successful.total", total)
          monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.successful.deleted", deleted)
          monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.successful.updated", updated)
          monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.successful.inserted", inserted)
        case Success((sftpResult, _)) if !sftpResult.wasSuccessful =>
          val sw = new StringWriter
          sftpResult.getError.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw))
          log.error("Failed to send data: " + sw.toString)
          monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.sftp.failed", 1)
        case Failure(e: Throwable) =>
          val sw = new StringWriter
          e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw))
          log.error(sw.toString)
          monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.failed", 1)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think, what it says is that `wasSuccessful` is always true, so you don't need that check.

Answer (score 1):

Both [`wasSuccessful`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.7/akka/stream/IOResult.html#wasSuccessful:Boolean) and [`getError`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.7/akka/stream/IOResult.html#getError:Throwable) have been deprecated since `2.6`.  Since `IOResult` is in general wrapped in a `Future` which by itself already tells whether the I/O operation is a Success or Failure, the `status` parameter of a successfully returned `IOResult` is in essence redundant, thus is now always set to `Success[Done]`.

Given that, you could simplify/refactor your case matching snippet to something like below:

```
  tupleFutureToFutureTuple(result) andThen {
    case Success((sftpResult, updateList)) =>
      val total = updateList.size
      val deleted = updateList.count(_ == Operation.DELETED)
      val updated = updateList.count(_ == Operation.UPDATED)
      val inserted = updateList.count(_ == Operation.INSERTED)
      log.info(s"SUCCESS! Uploaded $total accounts to Equifax.")
      log.info(s"There were $deleted deletions, " +
        s"$updated updates and " +
        s"$inserted insertions to the database")
      monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.successful.total", total)
      monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.successful.deleted", deleted)
      monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.successful.updated", updated)
      monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.successful.inserted", inserted)
    case Failure(e: Throwable) =>
      val sw = new StringWriter
      e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw))
      log.error(sw.toString)
      monitor.gauge("upload.process.batch.failed", 1)
  }
```